# Using number of surjection

Tags: combinatorics

I was trying to show that :
$$n^{p} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} S_{p,k} $$
where $S_{p,k}$ : is the number of the surjection from a set of p elements to a set of n elements ,
I show so far that : 
$$ S_{p,n} = n(S_{p-1,n-1}+ S_{p-1,n})$$
I try induction but it doesn't seem to work .
Some help please!

Comment: Note that $n^p$ is the number of functions from a set of $p$ elements to a set of $n$ elements. Note that given any function of this type, there exists some subset of the $n$ range elements such that the function is surjective on that subset range. Do you see how to finish the argument?

Comment: Yeah, I see it now . Thank you